# Undo git filter-branch

Tags: git

I accidentally delete a file from my repo using git filter-branch:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch images/thumb/a.JPG' HEAD
```

How can I undo this? Is it possible? i.e. is the file permanently deleted?

Comment: Question of the year right now

Answer (score 159, accepted):

When you use `git filter-branch`, a backup file is created in

```
refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

If you used the command in branch `master`. You can check if you have the backup in `.git/refs` directory. With this in mind, you can use this backup to recover your files with:

```
git reset --hard refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Comment: I got the error message `fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.`, so instead I first did `git reflog` and found the line `HEAD@{integer}: filter-branch: rewrite`, then I noted down the integer and performed `git reset --hard HEAD@{integer}` and I was back.

Comment: This worked for me. I included `git push -f` after `git reset --hard HEAD@{integer}`

Comment: I wanted to use `git filter-branch` to remove a enormous amount of lines, from someone accidentally committing a library to our repo. So in the graph, it shows like 8000 lines of addition/deletion, I thought filter-branch was was gonna rewrite. And the graph would update, but it didn't. It doubled all the lines. Will doing this bring the line count to the old state? or double it again?!

Comment: Yes, this command will return your code to the state before the 'filter-branch' command.

Comment: Thank you for resetting my heart attack. Worked flawlessly after a filter command removed everything but a folder.

Comment: Thanks a million! I would put two thumbs up if possible.

Comment: You are a true champion

Comment: How can I remove the backup? (once I am satisfied with filter-branch result)
I am deleting the .git/refs/original folder and it works, but I wonder if a more elegant git command exists for the purpose. Thanks

Comment: Man! you just saved my job!

Answer (score 35):

Probably a more proper way than just doing hard reset to the original master would be to restore **all** refs rewritten by `git filter-branch`, and maybe even delete backup refs afterwards in order to be able to invoke `git filter-branch` again without `--force`:

```bash
for orig_ref in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/); do
    git update-ref "${orig_ref#refs/original/}" $orig_ref
    git update-ref -d $orig_ref  # to also remove backup refs
done
```

And after that:

```bash
git reset --hard master
```

### UPD.

Here's (arguably) a bit more git'ish way to perform the same without a shell for-loop:

```bash
git for-each-ref --format="update %(refname:lstrip=2) %(objectname)" refs/original/ | git update-ref --stdin
git for-each-ref --format="delete %(refname) %(objectname)" refs/original/ | git update-ref --stdin
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe this script should be on the [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) documentation page, since it doesn't have any instructions on how to restore from the backup.

Comment: You're welcome! And you could always suggest an enhancement to their docs, I guess ;-)

Comment: How about the suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23483576/281545 - `git fetch . +refs/original/*:*` ?

Comment: I *think* I still needed to re-pull tags from upstream after doing this. Would that be expected?

Comment: @SamBrightman The man page doesn't mention that, and I don't know TBH...

Answer (score 7):

A much cleaner solution is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23483576/281545) by @jthill.

```
git fetch . +refs/original/*:*
```

As noted in that answer you may need to detach the HEAD if the currently checked out branch is to be restored.

To delete the `refs/original` refs, issue:

```
git for-each-ref refs/original --format='delete %(refname) %(objectname)' | git update-ref --stdin
```

Comment: This is definitely a simpler solution if you have multiple branches to restore. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that your old branch tip will be preserved in your [reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html). Then you should be able to check out the unchanged commit with all the previous history.

Comment: git reflog... Hurray.. this command have saved me countless times. :)

Comment: Yep this solved it for me and seemed like the simplest solution. Found the reflog entry I wanted to revert to (which happened to be `HEAD@{5}`) and ran `git reset HEAD@{5}`. For more details can checkout this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog).