# undo "git filter-branch ... -- --all"? in one command?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I started messing around with `git filter-branch`.  The --all option rewrites all branches and tags.  Cool.  `git filter-branch` creates a backup of all refs it overwrites in refs/original.  Very Cool.  Now I'd like to blow all my experimenting with `filter-branch` away.

**Is there an easy way to completely undo the effects of `git filter-branch <whatever filter> -- --all`?  I.e. to restore all of the rewritten branches to their original state all at once?**

If there isn't a preexisting way, there should be.  If there isn't a preexisting way, does anybody have a short script that will do it?

Obviously there's workarounds.  I could restore it manually, a branch at a time, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542326/undo-git-filter-branch).  Or I could just nuke and re-clone.  Either would get tedious quickly in a repo with many branches/tags that is (say) being split up into smaller repos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo git filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542326/undo-git-filter-branch)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple and safe way to undo a filter-branch:

```
git fetch . +refs/original/*:*
```

If the currently checked out branch (`HEAD`) is one of the branches to be restored, this command will fail. You can run `git checkout --detach` beforehand to let `git fetch` update all branches. Remember to checkout a branch after running `git fetch`!

Once the refs have been successfully restored, you can delete the `refs/original` refs safely with this command:

```
git for-each-ref refs/original --format='delete %(refname) %(objectname)' | git update-ref --stdin
```

---

*Old answer:*

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads refs/tags \
        --format='git update-ref "%(refname)" "%(refname)@{1 hour ago}"'
```

For added safety you could test whether the filter-branch actually did update the ref:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads refs/tags --format='
        { git reflog -1 "%(refname)" | sed -n "/filter-branch: rewrite$/Q1"; } \
                  || git update-ref -m "reset to before filter-branch" \
                             %(refname) %(refname)@{1}' | sh -x
```

Comment: This looks like a good script solution (and parsing it expanded my sed and git horizons).  The use of git update-ref should make it safer than manual copying of files (according to the git docs).  It mostly worked when I tried it, but I also got some errors like `fatal: Log for 'refs/remotes/origin/master' only has 1 entries.`  Haven't yet gotten to the bottom of why.  sh -x is also a nice touch, though the output is garbled for some reason.  I suspect that the output from subprocesses are racing to the terminal output and getting printed all over each other.

Comment: Yes, should probably make it `git for-each-ref refs/heads refs/tags --format=etc.`.  Fixed.

Comment: Thing is, if git tried to implement a pushbutton for every sometimes-very-useful-thing you can achieve with a few lines of script, it'd take longer to find the pushbutton that does what you want than to just implement it.

Comment: on that last comment, I most strongly disagree.  In my experience, the "not being able to find the button" problem is a deficiency in careful design of the user interface/experience (a front where git has been historically lacking), not necessarily a "too many features" problem.  Not that I'm complaining too much: I use git for everything, and also understand implementation triage :-).

Answer (score 2):

Ehmm, move all refs from `.git/refs/original` to their place in `.git/refs/heads`? I mean literally move, these are plain text files. Also you may take a look into `.git/packed-refs` if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  I knew that those files existed and what they did, but messing around manually in the .git folder seemed to be courting disaster.  I did this: 
`cd myrepo/.git/refs/original`
`cp -r refs/* ..`
and that seemed to do the trick.  That packed-refs file worries me, though.  I know that packed-refs is used as a fallback if the file doesn't exist.  I presume that `git filter-branch` doesn't touch packed-refs.  Are there any other gotchas here?

Comment: `packed-refs` is created during `git gc` and used as a fatser alternative to files in `.git/refs`. Usually, it's not a problem since entries in .git/refs override it, and `git filter-branch` is a quite rare operation so no need to "automate things", but just to be sure that everything is under your control :)