# How do I undo a Git Author Rewrite

Tags: git, bitbucket, author

Earlier today, following the instruction on this [previous stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git), I carelessly ran the following bit of code:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Newname'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='newemail';
```

And in doing so, I overwrite my coworker's 4048 commits on my particular branch. I attempted to

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

But this does not undo my author overwrite. Is there anyway for me to undo this commit thievery?

Comment: I was able to reset this to the previous author listing by following the directions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210446/replace-local-branch-with-remote-branch-entirely

git reset did not work by itself to replace the original author content. I had to delete my branch, and repull it, and then refetch it to restore the author content.

Comment: Filter branch makes a backup of your original refs in refs/original.  You needed to `git reset --hard refs/original/YOUR_BRANCH`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo git filter-branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542326/undo-git-filter-branch)