# Revert git commad (filter-branch)?

Tags: git, github

I had a finished a project but could not upload it to git because of a huge file with more than 100MB because git doesn't allow it.

So I deleted the file, and I was still getting the same error.

I eventually found this a discussion that told me to run the following command that deletes git's cache:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <file/dir>' HEAD
```

However, thanks to a typo I ran

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch ./' HEAD
```

And it **deleted** the entire project. I tried to revert to a previous commit but was unable to.

How can I revert this command?

Please help, I am rather desperate...

Comment: Project Backup? System Backup?

Comment: Is that really the best you have? My day is already ruined, I don't need you mocking me.

Comment: wasn't intended to mock you. sometimes the best solutions are directly in front of us. eftshifts proposal sounds promising

Comment: @Pat_Morita I don't know how DanielSan coped with you :-D Asking for a backup is like asking if you have **tzar bomba** under your bed, just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I think that filter-branch creates a backup of the preexisting branches IDs.

[Undo git filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542326/undo-git-filter-branch)