# git filter branch to git filter repo conversion

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am following this command to perform prettier over all commits in my git repository:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'prettier --write "**/**.js" || echo “Error formatting, possibly invalid JS“' -- --all
```

I want to perform the same in [git filter repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) but I am not even sure whether that is achievable. Can anyone help on how to approach this with git filter repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to perform the same in git filter repo but I am not even sure whether that is achievable

Yes, it is a [blob callback](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS) and allows you to call any script/command you want on said blob, similar to what is done in [newren/git-filter-repo issue 45](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/45#issuecomment-573339588), and [this example](https://gist.github.com/JacobHayes/9c86cc650c17a776f4a592fe0b2e7645)

```
git filter-repo --force --blob-callback '
  import black
  blob.data = black.reformat_commit(blob.data.decode(), mode=black.FileMode()).encode()
'
```

With [`reformat_commit` as in this python script](https://gist.github.com/JacobHayes/9c86cc650c17a776f4a592fe0b2e7645).